# How to call functions present in WPF projects from UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I am having one function to hide the taskbar in my WPF project, hiding taskbar is not possible in UWP, so i need to call that WPF function from UWP on button click,

How can i achieve that ?
i read something about desktop bridge , but i am not clear how to use it .

if anyone can give me simple example it will be great help

Answer (score 0):

> How to call functions present in WPF projects from UWP project

Sure, you could launch desktop extension with **parameter** from UWP app, then call the specific method base on this parameter. For more please refer stfan's blog **UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 2**, and it contains code sample.

Comment: I read that , i felt is it difficult , can you plz give me some simple example , like .. click btn from UWP application but call function from WPF one . it will be great help for me [I am new here]

Comment: Sure, I will make sample code for you, please wait a moment